# onCreateOptionsMenu vs onPrepareOptionsMenu

Tags: java, android, android-optionsmenu

What I am trying is to get a reference to Togglebutton, inside a custom menu item.

The menu is R.menu.main and the custom action layout R.id.action_rotation_switch and the actual button is R.id.rotationLockSwitch. Those are almost certaily correct. But when I start the activity, the menu.findItem(R.id.action_rotation_switch); returns a null pointer.
How is that possible? 
What is the correct way to use those two callbacks?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
    {            
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_rotation_switch);
    View v = item.getActionView();
    panRotSwitch = (ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.rotationLockSwitch);


    panRotSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sketchBoardFragment.lockRotation(panRotSwitch.isChecked());
        }
    });

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Comment: Is your drawer opened? It wouldn't inflate your menu and then that would explain why you get a null pointer exception when it tries to prepare the menu.

By the way, the onCreateOptionsMenu is only called once, when you open the menu for the first time. If you don't want your menu to show up if your drawer is opened, you should put your logic in onPrepareOptionsMenu since Android calls it everytime the menu is called

Comment: This happens at startup. Normally when it loads, the drawer is closed. I might check, which callback runs first.

Comment: @András Kovács are you using custom layout for ActionBar?

Comment: Yes, thats how it contains a ToggleButton.